# SIMD integer store

Tags: vectorization, sse, simd, mmx, sse3

I am writing a program using SSE instructions to multiply and add integer values. I did the same program with floats but I am missing an instruccion for my integer version.

With floats, after I have finished all my operations, I return de values back to a regular float array doing:

```
_mm_store_ps(temp4,temp3);
```

temp4 is a float *, and temp3 a __m128.

The problem is that I cannot find a similar intrinsic for intengers. How should I return the values back to a regular array?

Thanks a lot for your answers ;)

Answer (score 4):

See `_mm_load_si128`, `_mm_store_si128` (aligned) and `_mm_loadu_si128` `_mm_storeu_si128` (unaligned).

You might have overlooked these because for some reason the types are different compared to the float intrinsics. These are what lower to the `movdqa`/`movdqu` that you want.

Comment: But  _mm_store_si128 (__m128i *p, __m128i a) is moving data to a _128i type right?

With _mm_store_ps data was moved to a float array. If I need the integers back in an array of integers, can I use _mm_store_si128?

I think I could do a cast, but casting is pretty slow right?
Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Yes, you would need to cast the pointer you were storing to. Casting of this type is entirely free (although you are obliged to get the cast right!).